# Origin of "hike" in American football

Tags: etymology, terminology

Both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_%28gridiron_football%29) and [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hike) list the term *hike* as an alternative term for snapping the football at the beginning of play. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 5):

According to [VisualThesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/1983/), John Heisman originated the term in the 1890s:

> Back in the 1890s, John Heisman — of Heisman Trophy fame — introduced
>   the word *hike* to football. Originally, the center (who puts the ball
>   into play) used one hand to flip the ball under his legs to the
>   quarterback. To alert the center that he was ready to start, a
>   quarterback would use a touch signal, often scratching the center's
>   leg. When playing as a center for the University of Pennsylvania team
>   in 1890-91, Heisman got tricked by an opposing player who scratched
>   his leg. He flipped the ball back, and the quarterback missed the
>   pass. Heisman's solution was to have the quarterback use the word
>   *hike* to put the ball into motion so that everyone was clear when the play started. *Hike* was a good choice, since it can mean "to pull or
>   raise with a sudden motion," and that's what the center does with the
>   ball.