# Why do we use the term "hike" to describe an increase in price, value etc?

Tags: etymology

The earliest reference I can find in the OED to this sense of *hike* is from 1904.

> 1904   Topeka Capital 10 June 4   City Center kept the price of ice
>   cream sodas at five cents until the State Sunday School convention
>   struck town, and then the scale was hiked to ten cents.

We talk about a *hike in stock-market value*, *a hike in interest rates/rents/wages* etc.

It is also used as a transitive verb. But why is it *hike*?

Comment: Women have hiked up their skirts since [1925](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hiked+up+her+skirt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chiked%20up%20her%20skirt%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: There may be some connection between this sense and the verb "hike" in American football.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you have any reference for this, or can you explain further?Seems as if the usual sources do not mention it.

Comment: "Hike" is the term used in American football for when the "center" initially picks up the ball and either passes it to the quarterback or throws it to the kicker.  It's (very crudely stated) a sudden lifting or throwing motion.  The rise in popularity of the word "hike" would appear to parallel reasonably well the rise in popularity of American football.

Comment: @HotLicks Someone needs to tell *Etymonline* and the *OED*.

Comment: I'm guessing OED doesn't care much about American football.  And the etymology presumably is unaffected by the football use of the term, even if football "promoted" the use of the term.

Comment: @HotLicks You guess wrong. The OED considers itself the leading authority on the English language, as it is spoken around the world. And *hike* meaning *increase* is a widely used term. They would want to be right about the etymology if it were available.

Comment: Well, you'd have to ask OED why the sense of *hike* used in American football is not listed -- you certainly can't claim that the usage is "wrong".

Comment: @HotLicks Isn't sense 2b of the verb *to hike* closer to the mark?
*b. intr. To work upwards out of place. Const. up. c1873   M. Schele de Vere MS. Notes 488 (D.A.E.),   What makes y[ou]r dress hike up so?1890   Dial. Notes I. 61   The curtain hikes or hikes up.1902   G. H. Lorimer Lett. Merchant ix. 119   We boys who couldn't walk across the floor without feeling that our pants had hiked up till they showed our feet to the knee,..didn't like him.1948   Sat. Evening Post 4 Dec. 127/2   When I sit down, it hikes up.*

Comment: I would assume there are several senses that are close to the football meaning.  I'm not arguing that there should be a separate entry in OED for American football, you are.

Comment: @HotLicks If it is a widespread use of the term there is no reason why there shouldn't be.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52714/origin-of-hike-in-american-football

Answer (score 1):

According  Etymonline the meaning of "raise'  is probably from the sense  of "pull up", a variant of "hitch" ( from Middle English *hytchen, hichen, icchen* ‎, “to move, jerk, stir”).

***[Hike](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hike)***:

> - Sense of "pull up" (as pants) first recorded 1873 in American English, and may be a variant of hitch; ***extended sense of "raise" (as wages) is 1867.***

Comment: Does anyone ever say *he hiked his trousers up*?

Comment: @WS2 - The idiomatic phrasing is "hiked up", with the words together in that order.  I have heard/read phrases such as yours (and it doesn't really raise eyebrows) but it's not the usual word ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Following the football thread, I find [this](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/hut-the-story-behind-a-football-interjection/):

> The sport of football, meanwhile, was developing its own
>   interjections. Back in the 1890s, John Heisman — of Heisman Trophy
>   fame — introduced the word *hike* to football. Originally, the center
>   (who puts the ball into play) used one hand to flip the ball under his
>   legs to the quarterback. To alert the center that he was ready to
>   start, a quarterback would use a touch signal, often scratching the
>   center's leg. When playing as a center for the University of
>   Pennsylvania team in 1890-91, Heisman got tricked by an opposing
>   player who scratched his leg. He flipped the ball back, and the
>   quarterback missed the pass. Heisman's solution was to have the
>   quarterback use the word hike to put the ball into motion so that
>   everyone was clear when the play started. *Hike* was a good choice,
>   since it can mean "to pull or raise with a sudden motion," and that's
>   what the center does with the ball.
>
> Soon after, as a coach, Heisman introduced the "direct snap," where
>   the ball is "hiked" in the now-familiar way. Previously, the ball
>   would be rolled back along the ground or snapped end over end (a
>   "snapback"). In 1893, when Heisman was the coach at Buchtel College
>   (now the University of Akron), he had a very tall quarterback who had
>   trouble with the ball being rolled to him. So Heisman invented the
>   direct snap to allow the center to toss the ball directly up to the
>   quarterback. Every other college team followed Heisman's lead.

The author of the above piece (Ben Zimmer) did not say where he got "to pull or raise with a sudden motion", but he implies that this was a definition that was operative in the 1890s.  And one can see that it's consistent with "price hike" and similar uses.